# App Crashes after Button is Pressed

Tags: ios, swift, button

When my app loads, a microphone appears on the screen. When you tap the microphone a label that says "Recording" pops up along with a stop button. When you tap the stop button, the app crashes.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var recordingInProgress: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Hides the stop button
    stopButton.hidden = true
}


@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    //Shows the stop button
    stopButton.hidden = false

    //Shows the recording label
    recordingInProgress.hidden = false

    //TODO: Record Audio
    print("Recording in Progress.")

    }
```

This is my crash report:

Recording in Progress.
Recording in Progress.
2015-10-20 15:44:48.247 Vex[1468:533404] -[Vex.ViewController stopButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d5418a0
2015-10-20 15:44:48.253 Vex[1468:533404] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Vex.ViewController stopButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d5418a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183be4f5c 0x1987dbf80 0x183bebc6c 0x183be8c14 0x183aecdcc 0x1891723c8 0x189172344 0x18915ac6c 0x189171c5c 0x18917188c 0x18916aac0 0x18913ba10 0x189139efc 0x183b9c5a4 0x183b9c038 0x183b99d38 0x183ac8dc0 0x18ec1c088 0x1891a2f44 0x1000322b0 0x1990068b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Crashes with what? Crash message / signal? etc?

Comment: show your crash report

Comment: I added my crash report @LordZsolt

Comment: where is your `stopButton(_:)` function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

```
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
```

is connected on your storyboard to the actual button.

Answer (score 0):

if you use storyBoard check the IBAoutlet connection , maybe you connect it twice to the class . please tell the result

Answer (score 0):

you should check on storyboard/xib that your stop button Touch Up Inside Event is correctly linked with recordAudio action.

otherwise post your log.

Comment: I added the crash report.

Comment: @FelixDoe seems it's a problem on Storyboard. Could you past Connection inspector tab of your button?